# Ionic Vue iOS features

Tags: ios, vue.js, ionic-framework, dynamic-island

is there any way of interacting with dynamic island on iOS with Ionic framework? I want to display some things there when the app is minimized on background. Is it possible with anything?

Tried some components but I want the native experience

Comment: Not possible to interact with dynamic island on iOS with Ionic framework.